# How to create Android like share intent from website

Tags: html, facebook, google-plus

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Refer Us", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, context.getString(R.string.refer));
                    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    ((Activity) context).startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Hello, I share simple text messages using this share intent on Android.

To be specific can I do the same to Google plus and Facebook using Website calls.

Let me elaborate, can i Share content on Google + or Facebook, where Login and post is handled by google or Facebook respectively, like in android?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both of those services have functionality to share via a simple URL:

Google Plus: https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#share-link

Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#redirect